# replace NOT IN with LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a table structure like this

```
[condition]
    condition_id, (pk)
    question_id (fk)

[option]
    condition_id, (fk)
    ext_id (fk)

[external]
    ext_id, (pk)
    inst_id (fk)

[instance]
    inst_id, (pk)
    keeper_id (fk)

[keeper]
    keeper_id, (pk)
    org_id

[question]
    question_id (pk)
    org_id

[localization]
    question_id (fk, pk),
    org_id (pk),
    language (pk)
    label
```

I need to get all questions from `question` table with localizations (from `localization` table), that do not exist in `condition` table for certain `ext_id`.

My query is

```
SELECT
    q.question_id as q_id,
    l.label as q_value
FROM question q
    INNER JOIN localization l
        ON l.question_id = q.question_id
    INNER JOIN external ex
        ON ex.ext_id = 'EXTERNAL_ID'
    INNER JOIN instance i
        ON i.inst_id = ex.inst_id
    INNER JOIN keeper k
        ON k.keeper_id = i.keeper_id
WHERE q.org_id IN ('*', k.org_id)
    AND l.org_id = '*'
    AND l.language = 'EN'
    AND q.question_id NOT IN (
        SELECT
            question_id
        FROM condition c
            INNER JOIN option o
                ON o.condition_id = c.condition_id
        WHERE o.ext_id = 'EXTERNAL_ID'
    )
```

But how to replace that subquery with LEFT JOIN?

Comment: please specify rdbms

Comment: @swe updated tags

Comment: Your query is not syntactically correct.  What is `lq`?  What is `p`?

Comment: Why do you need to replace it with a `LEFT JOIN`? Why does `NOT EXISTS` not work for you?

Comment: @DStanley well I thought subqueries work slower than joins

Comment: Not necessarily.  SQL is declarative - meaning you tell it what results you want and the engine determines the "best" plan.  It's possible that the queries would have the same plan.  That said, there's no harm in trying it both ways and measuring the difference.

Comment: @DStanley Oh I see. So it depends...

Comment: @user1432980: Postgres as a pretty good query optimizer. The NOT IN solution is not necessarily slower then a solution with an outer join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way

```
SELECT p.question_id AS q_id,
       l.label       AS q_value
FROM   question q
       INNER JOIN localization l
               ON l.question_id = q.question_id
       INNER JOIN EXTERNAL ex
               ON ex.ext_id = 'EXTERNAL_ID'
       INNER JOIN instance i
               ON i.inst_id = ex.inst_id
       INNER JOIN keeper k
               ON k.keeper_id = i.keeper_id
       LEFT JOIN (select distinct c.question_id 
             from  condition c
              JOIN option o
              ON o.condition_id = c.condition_id
                 AND o.ext_id = 'EXTERNAL_ID' ) c 
              ON c.question_id = q.question_id
WHERE  q.org_id IN ( '*', k.org_id )
       AND l.org_id = '*'
       AND l.language = 'EN'
       AND c.question_id IS NULL
```

I am not a expert in Postgres but I prefer `NOT EXISTS` to do this

```
SELECT p.question_id AS q_id,
       l.label       AS q_value
FROM   question q
       INNER JOIN localization l
               ON l.question_id = q.question_id
       INNER JOIN EXTERNAL ex
               ON ex.ext_id = 'EXTERNAL_ID'
       INNER JOIN instance i
               ON i.inst_id = ex.inst_id
       INNER JOIN keeper k
               ON k.keeper_id = i.keeper_id
WHERE  q.org_id IN ( '*', k.org_id )
       AND l.org_id = '*'
       AND l.language = 'EN'
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM   condition c
                              INNER JOIN option o
                                      ON o.condition_id = c.condition_id
                       WHERE  o.ext_id = 'EXTERNAL_ID'
                              AND q.question_id = c.question_id)
```

Comment: Hm, first query returns less records than second one

Comment: @user1432980 - Check now

Comment: assuming before `(` should be `LEFT JOIN` it returns correct amount of records. I had the same issue when I tried to convert to pure `LEFT JOIN`. What is the problem?

Comment: @user1432980 - That is because you may have one to many relationship between tables. It could be between `question` and `condition` table or `condition` and `Order` table

Comment: I see. Thanks for explanation